# Clearing Screen in C++/XCode

Tags: c++, xcode

I am trying to write up a C++ program for a class using XCode. One of the things I wish to do, is to simply clear the screen. I've looked into how to do this, however the catch is that the code needs to run on both a Windows and Macintosh computer. I've looked at some other similar questions, but none of the answers help me. I know there is no "screen" but I want the system to clear the output window. I know that the command `system("clear");` does what I want it to, but when XCode tests the program, instead of clearing the screen it prints `TERM Variable not set`

I've tried opening up the terminal and typing `clear` and it does in fact respond the way I want it to, so why doesn't the 'terminal' inside of XCode do the same? I just want to get the output window in XCode to respond to `clear` the same way that the terminal already does.

Here is something I have already tried;

I went to the terminal and ran `echo $TERM`, to which the terminal responded `xterm-256color`. I then went over to XCode and opened the "Scheme" settings, and found an Environment Variables setting under "Arguments". I added a variable (to the blank list) called `TERM` and gave it value `xterm-256color`. Upon running the program again, the output displays `¿[H¿[2J` in the output window, positioned where the `TERM Variable not set` used to be printed.

Last thing, as a reminder, I **cannot** change the source code from the way it is now, or it could cause errors when the program is run on a Windows machine.

Comment: It is operating system specific. You might consider using [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you are "lying": The terminal in Xcode is not a `xterm-256color`, but it is `dumb` terminal. More precise, the display represents a [NSTextStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSTextStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that collects `stdout` and/or (depending on target switch) `stderr`.

A dumb terminal is not able to clean the display. If you want to change this, you can write a plug-in similar to [Xcode-Colors](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XcodeColors) what adds the ability to understand ansi color codes.

However, if your requirement that the code simply run at Windows and OSX, you may stick with your solution `system("clear")`, since it works prefectly in the "normal" OSX terminal.

Comment: Alright, thanks. My only real issue with this is that I have to turn in the output to the program as well as the source code. I would rather avoid having to run the program both within XCode and outside of XCode to properly get output. Is there a way to set up XCode so it shows output as if a regular terminal?

Comment: Cut and paste from the lines you need.