# Eclipse layout preview can't resolve custom attribute, ok in runtime

Tags: java, android, eclipse, svg, android-custom-view

I'm coding a simple class to use SVG resource:

```
public class SvgImageView extends ImageView {

    private int svgResourceId = 0;

    public SvgImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        parseAttributes(context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SvgImageView));
    }

    private void parseAttributes(TypedArray a) {
        this.svgResourceId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.SvgImageView_svg, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        // set correct layer type
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        // set drawable
        if (svgResourceId != 0)
setImageDrawable(SvgCache.getSvgPictureDrawable(getContext().getResources(), svgResourceId));
        }
    }
```

in the activity XML simply I use it:

```
<myapp.framework.widget.SvgImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            custom:svg="@raw/lighting" />
```

Everything works fine in runtime but in editor mode, when opening the Graphical Layout panel, when parsing attributes:

```
this.svgResourceId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.SvgImageView_svg, 0);
```

`this.svgResourceId` is 0, so I think it can't obtain the resource id. Why?

Comment: I can't offer a solution, but I can offer the consolation that this is only one of many, many defects and deficiencies in the Eclipse WYSIWYG  layout editor.   My advice, is edit the XML and view the results in the emulator.  Ignore the graphics editor.  Never, ever make changes in the graphics editor (it likes to trash XML files.)   Android Studio has a much better graphics layout editor, so there's hope in the future.

Comment: yeah, just wondering if someone has a quick solution. Really, Eclipse sucks sometime... ;)

Answer (score 0):

It may be the same situation as I had recently. To sum it up, it's because the IDE (Eclipse) processes the code with a different output method, resulting in the different display.

Here's a link to the question I had asked, hope it helps. [Clearing Screen in C++/XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908128/clearing-screen-in-c-xcode)

Comment: Really? Are you sure? We're talking about android and Eclipse environment!

Comment: @Seraphim'shost It sounds like the same kind of problem to me. I know the languages and IDE's are different, but the issue looks similar. I'm not saying the problem is exactly the same, as I've never worked with the language, but like Dale Wilson commented on the question itself, sometimes the editors and compilers do more damage than help if you take the 'easy' way of building them. Code becomes inefficient, and if you want to do complex things later on, variables are confusing and convoluted, and the way that the editors make things work, don't always make sense to the human eye.

Comment: I suppose the problem is strictly related to an issue in how Eclipse resolves resources in the active context. Anyway thanks for your contribute.